# Does the Equal Areas approximation discretization preserve expectation and variance?

Tags: statistics

What is Equal Areas discrete approximation of continuous random variables?

Comment: What is the "Equal Areas discrete approximation"? Nothing clear comes up when searching for it.

Comment: This is the only article I could find for it.
http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/10894_3819941_2/Attribute-Discretization--Using-the-147Equal-Areas148-Method.htm

Comment: What you posted seems to have more to do with computer systems than with mathematics. If you don't know what "Equal Areas discrete approximation" means yourself, how do you expect others to answer your question?

Comment: IMHO, having briefly browsed the paper at the link (which might have been included in the original question), this is a statistical question within the scope of our (statistics) tag. The paper is not clear about the traditional (pre-computational era) roots of the proposed method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to answer this question as I understand it, based on a quick scan
of parts of the article linked in your Comment.

'Discretization' or 'discrete approximation' of a continuous distribution
means (a) to divide the possible continuous values into non-overlapping intervals
( or 'bins') that cover the entire span of the observed data and then (b) to assign increasing numerical values (often integers) to bins of increasing continuous values.

'Equal areas' means that the bins contain (about) the same numbers of
subjects so that corresponding population bins are of (about) equal probability.
Then the integers that correspond to the bins are (about) equally likely.
It seems the rationale for wanting equal probabilities is to simplify simulations, because the integers representing the bins can be sampled
strictly at random.

The answer to your question is that means and standard deviations can be
approximately preserved if the discretization is done with care. Some information is lost when continuous values are
reduced to bins (and then integer values), so the preservation cannot be
exact. In general, the greater the number of bins, the greater the accuracy.

For example, suppose the population of some test scores is distributed $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 100,\,\sigma = 15), $ 
 and you have $n = 10\,000$ observations from that distribution.
Then you could pick cutpoints between ten bins roughly to match the deciles
of the sample. Here is a specific example with data simulated using
R statistical software:

```
set.seed(1234); n = 10000  
x = rnorm(n, 100, 15)
mean(x);  sd(x)
## 100.0917       # exact sample mean
## 14.81294       # exact sample SD

q = quantile(x, (0:10)/10); q
       0%       10%       20%       30%       40%       50% 
 49.05905  81.07926  87.44960  92.54443  96.54166 100.06952 
      60%       70%       80%       90%      100% 
103.80729 107.79283 112.57182 118.96523 154.27160
```

So that the bins are roughly $[49.06, 81.08), [81.08, 87.49), \dots
[112,57, 118.97), (118.97, 154,28].$

For comparison, here is a plot of the population density of $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 100,\,\sigma = 15),$
with vertical lines at *population* deciles. The lines divide the area under the
curve into ten equal parts (although, due to an optical illusion the outer
areas may look larger at first, or even second, glance).

[image]

Notice that the sample mean and SD of the 10,000 ("continuous") observed values are not far from the population mean
and SD, respectively.

We can use the `hist` function in R to get the corresponding interval
midpoints (rounded to integers) and frequencies.

```
hist.stats = hist(x, br=q, plot=F)
f = hist.stats$counts
m = round(hist.stats$mids)
f; m
## 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000  # frequencies
## 65   84   90   95   98  102  106  110  116  137    # midpoints
```

Thus we have completed the 'equal areas discretization', where the integers
that represent the bins are their rounded midpoints.

Now the sample mean $A = \bar X$ and standard deviation $S$ can be
approximated as $100.3$ and $18.4,$ respectively, using the formulas

$$\bar X \approx \frac{\sum_{j=1}^{10} f_jm_j}{n}\;\;\text{and}\;\;\;
S \approx \sqrt{\frac{\sum_j f_j(m_j - \bar X)^2}{n-1}}.$$

```
a = sum(f*m)/n;  s = sqrt(sum(f*(m-a)^2)/(n-1))
a;  s
## 100.3         # aprx 'discretized' sample mean
## 18.36964      # aprx 'discretized' sample SD
```

For many purposes these would be useful approximations of $\bar X$ and $S$
and thus useful estimates of the population $\mu$ and $\sigma.$

*Note:* Without the 'equal area' restriction, this method was used before the
computer age to simplify computations of sample means and SDs. 
Traditionally, it is the bin *widths* that are made equal, not the
bin *frequencies*. Nowadays, the histogram procedures in most statistical
software make histogram bins of equal widths by default.

The same formulas as above
(involving bin frequencies and midpoints) can be used to approximate
$\bar X$ and $S.$  In general, I suppose the method of equal widths
gives somewhat better approximations of $\bar X$ and $S.$ Below is a
histogram of the simulated $X_i$s above, with frequency labels atop
histogram bars.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.